# ios - tcp ip crash

Tags: ios, cocoa, stream, nsurlconnection, tcpclient

I've a tcp stream connection to send a giant NSDictionary of contacts, one by one, from the cellphone to a server. IF that NSDictionary has 50 entries, it goes ok, but it there are about 200 the app crashes after sending about 150 155 contacts. I think that it could be a memory problem, or there is some limit to stream connections? If there is a memory problem, like I'm with ARC on, how do I solve it?

Response handling (where I think that could be the problem, specially because the stream is getting closed a lot of times):

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

  NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);
  recebeuResposta=YES;
  switch (streamEvent) {

  ```
  case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
      NSLog(@"Stream opened");
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       postNotificationName:@"serverResponseArrived"
       object:nil];
      break;
  case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

      if (theStream == inputStream) {

          uint8_t buffer[10240];
          int len;

          while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
              len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
              if (len > 0) {

                  NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                      //NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                  NSArray *firstSplit = [output componentsSeparatedByString:@"=end="];
                      // NSLog(@"firstSplit, %@",[firstSplit objectAtIndex:0]);
                  NSError *parseError = nil;
                  NSDictionary *outputDictionary =[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
                  outputDictionary = 
                  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [[firstSplit objectAtIndex:0] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] 
                                                  options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                    error: &parseError];                        
                      //    NSLog(@"server said outputDictionary: %@", outputDictionary);

                  if (nil != output) {
                      if([(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"connect"])
                      {
                              //  NSLog(@"stream with server is opened. ready to send contacts.");
                              //   NSLog(@"action: %@",(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"action"]);
                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                           postNotificationName:@"beginSyncronization"
                           object:nil];
                      }else if([(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"add"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"type"]isEqualToString:@"response"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"result"]isEqualToString:@"done"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"element"]isEqualToString:@"contact"])
                      {
                              //    NSLog(@"enviar data");
                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                           postNotificationName:@"sendNextContact"
                           object:nil];
                              //[self prepareDetails];
                      }else if([(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"add"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"type"]isEqualToString:@"response"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"result"]isEqualToString:@"error"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"element"]isEqualToString:@"contact"])
                      {
                              //     NSLog(@"action: %@",(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"action"]);
                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                           postNotificationName:@"sendSameContactTCP"
                           object:nil];
                      }else if([(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"SyncMobile"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"type"]isEqualToString:@"response"]&&[(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"result"]isEqualToString:@"error"])
                      {
                              //   NSLog(@"action: %@",(NSString*)[outputDictionary objectForKey:@"action"]);
                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                           postNotificationName:@"sendSameContactTCP"
                           object:nil];
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }else{
          NSLog(@"STREAM HAS NO BYTES! %@:",theStream);
      }
      break;


  case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

      NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
      break;

  case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

      NSLog(@"Stream closed");
      [theStream close];
      [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
      theStream = nil;
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sendSameContactTCP" object:self];
      break;
  default:
      NSLog(@"Unknown event");
   /*   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       postNotificationName:@"sendSameContactTCP"
       object:nil];*/
  ```

  }

}

Comment: You have to show some of the code that transmit the data. We cannot guess what you might have written incorrectly.

Comment: I updated the question with the code where I make the handling of responses by the server. I think that the problem is when the stream closes. I tried to restart the stream in that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the CocoaAsyncSocket library from robbiehanson instead, and it's faster and stable:

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

If you have to make socket connections I highly recommend using it, it's a lot faster and simpler (at least for me).